# How to directly call in mobile by pressing link

Tags: html

I am trying to allow user call in mobile phones as in

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

such that when user press the link, then it not only opens the number for calling but actually makes the call too at the same time (aka saves user one step to press button).

Also I need to add an extra code number (lets say 2525 ) dialled when call is connected. Is that possible? This is HTML5 website.

Answer (score 2):

The function of clicking the link will depend on the platform, so this cannot be changed in your code. Most platforms such as iOS do not connect to the number without confirmation as a security measure.

To add the extra code number once the call has been connected, try using the `p`.

```
<a href='tel:14085555555p2525'>1-408-555-5555</a>
```

However I haven't tried this so I'm not sure whether this will work.

Comment: Ok that is good to know. However, is it possible to automatically add extra code 4 digit code number when call is connected after user presses call button?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't tested it, but try inserting a 'p' after the number, and then put your extension number. This should dial the extension after the call has been connected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the dialler functionality of the phone which is not possible and as per mobile OS are considered they wont allow it due to security measures.